# Pydub error loading file: Unknown encoder 'pcm_s4le'

Tags: python, audio, wav, pydub

I want to load my audio into python so that I can cut parts of it together and then resave as a shorter file.  Pydub is in theory perfect for this.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks
from pydub.utils import which

AudioSegment.converter = which("ffmpeg")
myaudio = AudioSegment.from_file(path+ wavfile+".wav" , "wav")
```

However I get the following error on trying to load the file.

```
ffmpeg version 2021-04-11-git-309e3cc15c-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
libavutil 56. 72.100 / 56. 72.100
libavcodec 58.136.101 / 58.136.101
libavformat 58. 78.100 / 58. 78.100
libavdevice 58. 14.100 / 58. 14.100
libavfilter 7.111.100 / 7.111.100
libswscale 5. 10.100 / 5. 10.100
libswresample 3. 10.100 / 3. 10.100
libpostproc 55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from 'D:/OneDrive/DataSci/Tennis/01_data/201121_SebMatch/JJO_ingameAUDIO.wav':
Duration: 00:48:03.03, bitrate: 192 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: adpcm_ima_wav ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, mono, s16p, 192 kb/s

**Unknown encoder 'pcm_s4le'**
```

I do not see this specific error on any questions, and have logged the question on the git respository for pydub  [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/583)
There is also an example testfile to test upon.  Whilst this is not the actual file I want to process (which is 70mb), this generates the same output.

I managed to load the file using soundfile, but when I sliced the data, it then wouldn't let me export it as they were 2 different lengths.  Hence I went back to pydub.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging around with other libraries, I found this [link which highlights the differnt methods for looking at the audio.](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/index.ipynb)

The soundfile demo shows how to identify the encoding using these lines:

```
f = sf.SoundFile('data/test_wav_pcm16.wav')
f.format, f.subtype, f.endian
```

This told me that my wav file was infact encoded with "IMA ADPCM".
I then loaded the file in soundfile, and resaved it as soundfile by default saves to PCM_16, which can then be recognised by pydub....